# Останутся ли на github коммиты + (зеленые кубики - актвность), при удалении файлов?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Подскажите пожалуйста, если я удаляю с GitHub папку с некоторыми файлами в проэкте, коммиты(+зеленные кубики активности) связаные с удаляемыми файлами, автоматически удалятся ?

Comment: Не удаляется. При подсчете активности учитываются пуши, а конкретные файлы - нет. Разве что если вы удалите репозиторий целиком, тогда вся активность с ним связанная также удалится.

Comment: @insolor спасибо большое!